# How do I get sensors-applet working?

Tags: 11.10, sensors

I used to have `lm-sensors` and `sensors-applet` working correctly on Ubuntu 11.04. I just updated to Ubuntu 11.10, and `lm-sensors` is installed, but **`sensors-applet`** does not seem to be in the repository any more. Is there a way to still have it working?

Comment: "...does not seem to be in the repository any more..." Uh... http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/lm-sensors

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I made a mistake. It was a different package that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing and using GNOME instead of Unity and following this guide ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=92504 ) allows you to use sensors-applet with ubuntu 11.10! (sensors-applet was removed from the 11.10 repo!!!)
Just make sure you download the current source of sensors-applet here http://sensors-applet.sourceforge.net/index.php?content=source

Comment: installation requires me to have gtk+-3.0 which is 745mb! Is there any way around that dependency?

Answer (score 3):

You'll be needing Alex Murray’s excellent Hardware Sensors Indicator for Unity. Only available from PPA at the moment:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

Comment: `add-apt-repository` succeeded, but I cannot `apt-get install` that. It says it cannot find it.

Comment: Strange, works for me... and still available. You are using Oneiric (11.10)?

Have a look at the ppa [link](https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/indicator-sensors)

Answer (score 2):

The psensor application lets you graph the fan/temperature info, but like you I am missing a notification-area indicator for this. Maybe Indicator-multiload could help, but it doesn't seem to present sensor information at the moment.
Indicators-sysmonitor seems only to function with CPU load at the moment, even though it presents lm-sensors information in its configuration.
Yet another edit:
[indicator-sensors](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/indicator-sensors-displays-cpu.html) does read lm-sensors inputs, and displays them, but only as a label/temp, not a graph. It does allow a high or low warning to be set though, so it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this direct link to download until the repository will be availabe for 12.04
http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-sensors/

I just tested and for me works great

Answer (score 0):

indicator-sensors from Alex Murray is excellent. Psensor is another similar tool, available in the stock Ubuntu repositories since Oneiric. You can find Ubuntu detailed installation instruction at: http://wpitchoune.net/blog/psensor/ubuntu-integration/.